# Как связать в php форму обратной связи и фото?

Tags: php, form, javascript

Создала форму обратной связи с высылкой фото. А вот в обработчике не могу их связать вместе. То есть, ответы на форму приходят на почту хостинга, а фото - в папку файлов (на хостинге). Как сделать, чтобы письмо приходило с вложением? Надо дописать аттактент и директорию для фото.

```
<?php  

$result = mail("badantecerco1@test.ru","Анкета беспл","Получена информация:  
Откуда $_POST[citta]\n  
Имя: $_POST[nome]\n   
Возраст: $_POST[eta]\n  
Национальность $_POST[naz]\n    
Сколько времени в Италии $_POST[quando]\n    
Режим работы $_POST[quale]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro1]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro2]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro3]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro4]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro5]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro6]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro7]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro8]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro9]\n  
Тип работы $_POST[lavoro10]\n  
Где ищет работу $_POST[dove]\n  
Переехать в пределах от города 10 км $_POST[citta1]\n  
Переехать в пределах от города 30 км $_POST[citta2]\n  
Переехать в пределах от города 50 км $_POST[citta3]\n  
Разговорный $_POST[par]\n  
Чтение $_POST[letto]\n  
Письмо $_POST[scri]\n  
Права $_POST[patente]\n  
Машина $_POST[mach]\n  
Дополнения $_POST[text]\n  
email $_POST[ind1]\n  
email $_POST[ind2]\n  
telef $_POST[telef1]\n  
telef $_POST[telef2]\n  
"  
);  
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.png','.JPG');  
 $max_filesize = 1524288;  
 $upload_path = './files/';  
  $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];  
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);  
   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))  
   die('Данный тип файла не поддерживается.');  
    if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)  
    die('Фаил слишком большой.');  
    if(!is_writable($upload_path))  
    die('Невозможно загрузить фаил в папку. Установите права доступа - 777.');     
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))   

if ($result)     
{  
echo '<center><b>Сообщение отправлено! В скором времени мы вам позвоним.<br>;  
<a href=index.html>Нажмите,</a> чтобы вернуться на главную страницу';  
}    
else {    
echo "<p>Сообщение не отправлено!</p>  
<p>Отправьте письмо на адрес badantecerco1@gmail.com </p>  
<p>ответьте на все вопросы и прикрепите фотографию.</p>";  
}  
?>
```

Comment: отформатируйте, пожалуйста, код

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не представляю, как это сделать. У меня таргет - женщины, которые понимают еле-еле как работать с сайтами. Они дожны заполнить форму и загрузить фотку, а по ним я им ищу работу. Ок? То есть максимум, что они смогут понять, - это заполнить поля и загрузить фото. Видите, я даже не ставлю контроль за заполнением полей...

Если вы поняли, что требуется, помогите - допишите или заново напишите, плииз. Мне нужно напустить сайт, я не смогу скоро им заниматься.

Comment: подправила код

Comment: Обратитесь на фриланс. Там вас за плату сделают всё что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

А что вам мешает в письме вставить изображение через `<img src="адрес_картинки">` или сделать в письме ссылку на загруженный файл `<a href="адрес_картинки">ссылка</a>` ?